# Nodejs oracledb package: Error: 'gyp' failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, node-oracledb

I have had a ton of issues installing `oracledb` on Windows 7. I'm getting the following error:

```
> oracledb@1.13.1 install C:\Users\alex.cauthen\Documents\CLA\cla_ui\node_module
s\oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\alex.cauthen\Documents\CLA\cla_ui\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined
npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp
-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebu
ild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_m
ain.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1900, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib
\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)

KeyError: '2017'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\alex.cauthen\Documents\CLA\cla_ui\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
cla_ui@1.0.0 C:\Users\alex.cauthen\Documents\CLA\cla_ui
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN cla_ui@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN cla_ui@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

For installing oracledb I followed this walkthrough: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127. Here is what I have done:

- I have visual studio 2012 installed
- I have python 2.7 installed
- I have node 6.10.2 and npm 3.10.10
- I have installed oracle instant client basic and sdk, extracted them to an instantclient folder in C:\oracle\instantclient
- Path env. variable = C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27\;C:\oracle\instantclient;
- Created env. variable OCI_LIB_DIR = C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\lib\msvc
- Created env. variable OCI_INC_DIR = C:\oracle\instantclient\sdk\include

Then the last thing I did after all of that was installed was do `npm install oracledb`. I'm at a loss on what to do. I've wasted a lot of time debugging/trying to get this installed. Let me know if you see anything I missed... and thanks for the help.

Alex